# How to avoid ImportError: No module named arcpy causing Failed to execute (Script) error?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcpy, arc-hydro

I have a proplem with arc hydro in arcpy,i want to create a simple script where automated some tools from archydro in arcpy..
I use arcmap 10.1 and python 1.7,my import is one dem and my export is a 6 raster file (fill,fdr,fac,cat,str,strlink) and run ok without proplem but if I add one more tool cachmented to polygon that converts a raster file to polygon feature class then show me error
i import this python script on arcmap

```
import arcpy

arcpy.ImportToolbox("C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\ArcToolbox\Toolboxes\Arc Hydro Tools.tbx", "archydrotools")
#Set Ouput Names
fill=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) + '\\fill'
Fdr=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) + '\\fdr'
Fac=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) + '\\fac'
Str=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) + '\\Str'
StrLnk=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) + '\\StrLnk'
Cat=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) + '\\Cat'
Catchment=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) + '\\Catchment'

# Local variables:
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
dem = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
# Process: Fill Sinks
arcpy.FillSinks_archydrotools(dem, fill, "", "", "ISSINK_YES")
# Process: Flow Direction
arcpy.FlowDirection_archydrotools(fill, Fdr, "")
# Process: Flow Accumulation
arcpy.FlowAccumulation_archydrotools(Fdr, Fac)
# Process: Stream Definition
arcpy.StreamDefinition_archydrotools(Fac, "", Str, "1")
# Process: Stream Segmentation
arcpy.StreamSegmentation_archydrotools(Str, Fdr, StrLnk, "", "")
# Process: Catchment Grid Delineation
arcpy.CatchmentGridDelineation_archydrotools(Fdr, StrLnk, Cat)
# Process: Catchment Polygon Processing
arcpy.CatchmentPolyProcessing_archydrotools(Cat, Catchment)
```

[image: my error]

but my export file in the folder they become export the all files regular

my proplem is the last command because is a feature class I think

any idea ?

Comment: Can you please use copy/paste to get sufficient lines of the error message captured and included so that there is a starting point for people to try and spot what is astray.  "Failed to execute (Script)" tells you/us next to nothing - I suspect you want to know why it failed to execute.  To see the whole tool output simply use the scroll bar on the dialog that you have screenshot.

Comment: You have now included your script but what is the more complete error message?

Comment: yes is a complete message from arcmap

Comment: What happens when you run your script from an IDE like Python with a hardwired values for the workspace that you are setting from the parameter of your dialog?  You should see a more informative error message then.

Comment: if run from python ide showed me that error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LG\Desktop\peiramata\pythotwo.py", line 9, in <module>
    import arcpy
ImportError: No module named arcpy

Comment: I DO NOT WANT TO RUN FROM THE PYTHON IDLE,I WANT TO IMPORT SCRIPT IN ARCMAP 10.1 FOR TO HELP MY WORK

Comment: Your best practice is going to be to get the entire script to work in IDLE first, then as a standalone script, then make that into a script tool. You don't want to be debugging errors like this in a script tool.

Comment: yes ok i try to best you are right

Answer (score 3):

You have now provided an error from IDLE in a Comment to your Question which is that it is:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:\Users\LG\Desktop\peiramata\pythotwo.py", line 9, in 
>   import arcpy ImportError: No module named arcpy

The error you are seeing has been reported several times on GIS SE (e.g. [Debugging ImportError: No module named arcpy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85408/error-importing-arcpy-python)).  It seems to indicate a problem with your PATH and/or PYTHONPATH environment variables.  A quick fix may be to uninstall/reinstall ArcGIS for Desktop which should set these straight.

Below this line is my earlier Answer, which I will leave here for now, and probably remove once this Question is resolved.

================================================================================

My suspicion is that the parts which work do so because you are writing the output raster files to a folder which you set using arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0).

However, when you try to run arcpy.CatchmentPolyProcessing_archydrotools I suspect that the tool is stuck between:

- trying to write a feature class to a geodatabase when you have provided a folder workspace; and
- trying to write a shapefile when you have not provided the *.shp extension.

Try setting this:

```
Catchment=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) + '\\Catchment.shp'
```

and I think it will work.

Comment: yes I tried export to a geodatabase,i tried and import new workspace only for cachment(shp) and i tried to *.shp extension and nothing no change for my proplem

Comment: can be to *feature class extension ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not a complete answer.
But consider converting your script to run as a script tool or standalone in a format like this. You might need to move the SA checkout to the top, since I am not sure what dependencies come into play when importing ArcHydro and how those time. This format will make debugging easier, as you can run standalone first for debugging, then switch to a script tool when you have the script running smoothly.

```
#Imports at the top
import arcpy
arcpy.ImportToolbox("C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\ArcToolbox\Toolboxes\Arc Hydro Tools.tbx", "archydrotools")


def main(root, dem):
    """Takes root as the root workspace and dem as the provided dem."""
    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
    arcpy.env.workspace = root
    #Set Ouput Names
    fill = root + '\\fill'
    Fdr = root + '\\fdr'
    Fac = root + '\\fac'
    Str = root + '\\Str'
    StrLnk = root + '\\StrLnk'
    Cat = root + '\\Cat'
    Catchment = root + '\\Catchment'
    # Process: Fill Sinks
    arcpy.FillSinks_archydrotools(dem, fill, "", "", "ISSINK_YES")
    # Process: Flow Direction
    arcpy.FlowDirection_archydrotools(fill, Fdr, "")
    # Process: Flow Accumulation
    arcpy.FlowAccumulation_archydrotools(Fdr, Fac)
    # Process: Stream Definition
    arcpy.StreamDefinition_archydrotools(Fac, "", Str, "1")
    # Process: Stream Segmentation
    arcpy.StreamSegmentation_archydrotools(Str, Fdr, StrLnk, "", "")
    # Process: Catchment Grid Delineation
    arcpy.CatchmentGridDelineation_archydrotools(Fdr, StrLnk, Cat)
    # Process: Catchment Polygon Processing
    arcpy.CatchmentPolyProcessing_archydrotools(Cat, Catchment)
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Expects two arguments, root folder and dem
    # This should work when called stand alone with script arguments, in idle with arguments provided, or in a script tool
    argv = tuple(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(i) for i in range(arcpy.GetArgumentCount()))
    main(*argv)
```

Comment: sorry for the stupid questions but I am very new to programming and thank you all for the answers..
root and dem is variables right ?

Comment: Yeah, so what is happening there is I am making a tuple, assigned to argv, out of the supplied arguments. The tuple is unzipped (the asterisk) into arguments that are supplied to the function main(). main() expects two arguments, which will then be assigned to the variables root and dem inside the function main().

Comment: yea ok I'm trying to understand that,but the variables is are different categories,the root is a workspace and dem is a raster dataset, how will the import declarations in arcmap ?normaly 2 variables where one is a workspace and two is a raster dataset ?

Comment: nothing i use your code and same error :( I'm desperate

Comment: Execute the code in IDLE first. After it fails, import sys in the interactive window, then type and provide back here the result: sys.modules['idlelib']

Comment: nothing again,i thing is not code error because the exports is integrators to in workspace folder

Comment: and i tried to import workspace to file geodatabase and nothing again

Comment: An ImportError has nothing to do with your workspaces. It means that the module you are importing (and the only one you import is arcpy) is not present. The result of sys.modules['idlelib'] would tell us where IDLE is executing, giving an idea why arcpy is not present.

Comment: if i run from idle i need to import arcpy with path (c:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2.2\arcpy) and show me syntax error `:`

Comment: Ah, I think I see your problem now. You have ArcGIS 10.2.2 installed. You are trying to import a 10.1 toolbox for ArcHydro which references 10.1 python libraries, which are no longer installed on your system. Go get the latest version of ArcHydro (10.2.0.38 from 2/13/2014) and install that. Use _that_ toolbox instead of the 10.1 toolbox. See if that improves things.

Comment: no no my mistake sorry my friend wrong copy-paste i have arcmap 10.1 sure my right path is C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy and show me syntax error for that (:) and sorry again

Comment: Okay, that is the right path for arcpy from sys.modules. what path are you getting for idlelib though? That will tell us more about the python instance being used.

Comment: idlelib path ? i dont know about that..is that? C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\bin or C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\ArcToolbox\Scripts ?

Comment: if import some variable to main is a right ?