# Object: Error in executing tool in arcpy address locator script

Tags: arcpy, geocoding, citrix

I have a python script I made into a tool that creates multiple address locators. I also have two separate machines that I access through citrix. Each machine has it's own instance of ArcMap installed. When I developed the tool on the first machine it ran fine. I then copied it over to the second machine which has the same architecture and now it's bombing. I pulled the script into PythonWin and hardcoded the inputs. I tried to get messages in try: except: clause but the program would just print the first print statement and then exit.

```
# Create street address locators using different street centerline feature classes 

# Import system modules
import arcpy
import os
from arcpy import env

outPath = r"C:RS_Data\Common\Locators"

arcpy.env.workspace = outPath
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

    # Get tool parameters from street centerline files
    mainRef = r"J:\Common\Map Clips\Street Layers\Features.gdb\CO_SF_2016_Q4_Merge" #arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
    aliasRef = r"J:\Common\Map Clips\Street Layers\Features.gdb\CO_SF_2016_q4_streets" #arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
    #aliasA_Ref = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

    #No need for output name until create comp address locator code works
    """outCompAdd = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)"""

    # make a list of the street centerline files 

    refData = [mainRef,aliasRef]

    # Create a loop that will create a separate address locator for each street centerline file
    for ref in refData:
        # create output name
        baseName = os.path.basename(ref)
        outName = os.path.join(outPath,baseName)
        print outName
        #create address locator
        arcpy.CreateAddressLocator_geocoding("RouteSmart - US Streets with Zone",ref,"'Street ID' link_id VISIBLE NONE;'*House From Left' L_REFADDR VISIBLE NONE;'*House To Left' L_NREFADDR VISIBLE NONE;'*House From Right' R_REFADDR VISIBLE NONE;'*House To Right' R_NREFADDR VISIBLE NONE;'Prefix Direction' ST_NM_PREF VISIBLE NONE;'Prefix Type' ST_TYP_BEF VISIBLE NONE;'*Street Name' ST_NM_BASE VISIBLE NONE;'Street Type' ST_TYP_AFT VISIBLE NONE;'Suffix Direction' ST_NM_SUFF VISIBLE NONE;'*Left Zone' L_POSTCODE VISIBLE NONE;'*Right Zone' R_POSTCODE VISIBLE NONE'",outName, "")
        message = "Created" + " " + outName
        arcpy.AddMessage(message)
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 323, in RunScript
    debugger.run(codeObject, __main__.__dict__, start_stepping=0)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\debugger\__init__.py", line 60, in run
    _GetCurrentDebugger().run(cmd, globals,locals, start_stepping)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\debugger\debugger.py", line 654, in run
    exec cmd in globals, locals
  File "J:\Common\Script\Drivers\Create_Address_Locators.py", line 4, in <module>
    import arcpy
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\geocoding.py", line 93, in CreateAddressLocator
    raise e
RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool
```

I'm afraid I haven't been able to get anything more helpful in a message, as I stated earlier, try and except just forces the program to exit.

Comment: I would check to see that arcpy is importing correctly on machine #2. Double check your PATH variables. See [here)](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85408/debugging-importerror-no-module-named-arcpy)

Comment: Just imported arcpy in the python cmd window on machine 2. No issues there.