# Correcting 'ImportError: No module named arcpy' without admin rights using Wing IDE 101 8

Tags: arcpy, importerror

> Error: 'ImportError: No module named arcpy'

I am new to Python programming (or any programming) and basically teaching myself.  I'm using Wing IDE 101 8 (recommendation from a previous coworker who does programming and said it is good for beginners). I do not have admin rights on my computer and cannot run the 'Edit the system variables' at this time.  I might be able to convince IT to do it, but at this point I do not know how to explain what it is, what it does, or why I might need to use it.  I tried to run through the instructions here: [Debugging ImportError: No module named arcpy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85408/debugging-importerror-no-module-named-arcpy) , but I'm at a loss.  I tried changing the pythonpath here:

[image]

with different locations including where the ArcPy module is located, but I still get the same error.

Versions I'm using:
Python 2.7.16 / ArcMap 10.7.1 \ ArcGIS Pro 2.5

I am hesitant to upgrade any of these versions as I'm new in this position and am not sure which scripts might be tied to which programs, etc.  I know some suggestions say to uninstall and resintall ArcMap, but that's a non-starter.  If I can't figure this out, would it better to just use Pythonwin, IDLE, or ArcGIS Pro's built in Python editor (already installed)?

Comment: Marking a habit of deleting and re-asking Questions is likely to spur the SE anti-spam defenses to block your account. The better solution is to Edit the existing Question. If you really are new to both programming and Python, it's probably a major mistake to use a 3rd-party IDE (not to mention a misconfigured IDE) so soon. If you use Idle and learn the language, then choosing a different IDE will be based on experience, not faulty advice.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Vince

Comment: Also, what do you mean, by faulty advice?